# Open two separate windows for preview in TeXShop

Tags: texshop, mac

I am using TeXShop on a Mac.

Sometimes, I wish to have two separate previews window for my output pdf so that I can look at, for example, page 23, when I edit page 12.

I know there is a small button on the upper right-hand side of preview window which can separate the PDF output into two parts, upper and lower. But what I want is to have two completely separate windows, so that I can put one in one screen and another one on my secondary screen.

Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with TeXShop directly. But you could open the document in e.g. Skim as well as TeXShop. Skim automatically updates the PDF when it changes.

Comment: Window --> "Split Window"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeXShop has no way to open two views of your PDF file in separate windows. But if you use an external PDF viewer that automatically updates open files when they change, you can easily open your document in the viewer and have that on one screen while the you work on the document in TeXShop at the same time.

[Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) is one such PDF viewer (and a really great program).  Apple's Preview can also do this.  Adobe Reader does not do automatic file refresh, however.

Comment: I should correct you: Preview *does* automatic refresh, at least on Mavericks.

Comment: @egreg you are right. But Preview will jump back to the top of pdf page when you update it...